# Find and replace case

Tags: r, replace

I have a dataset which contains four columns X1(id number), x2 (Datetime), x3 (Datetime), x4 (Duration)

```
 structure(list(X1 = c(549395L, 678018L, 706197L, 549395L, 775731L, 
 789858L, 845277L, 936749L, 845277L, 954953L), X2 = c("06/16/2014 10:45:24 AM", 
 "09/16/2014 10:02:46 AM", "02/12/2014 12:00:13 PM", "06/16/2014 10:45:24 AM", 
 "08/29/2014 8:42:34 AM", "02/26/2014 12:29:26 PM", "04/07/2014 1:49:04 PM", 
 "02/14/2014 12:02:29 PM", "05/18/2014 12:09:35 PM", "03/05/2014 9:47:11 AM"
 ), X3 = c("06/04/2014 11:10:03 AM", "09/16/2014 10:23:00 AM", 
 "02/12/2014 12:21:00 PM", "", "08/29/2014 8:51:03 AM", "02/26/2014 12:49:00 PM", 
 "04/07/2014 1:59:56 PM", "02/14/2014 12:08:00 PM", "", "03/05/2014 10:14:00 AM"
 ), X4 = c(8L, 21L, 10L, 72L, 39L, 14L, 41L, 31L, 43L, 24L)), .Names = c("X1", 
 "X2", "X3", "X4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
 ))

   X1     X2                     X3                      X4
   549395 06/16/2014 10:45:24 AM 06/04/2014 11:10:03 AM  8
   678018 09/16/2014 10:02:46 AM 09/16/2014 10:23:00 AM 21
   706197 02/12/2014 12:00:13 PM 02/12/2014 12:21:00 PM 10
   549395 06/16/2014 10:45:24 AM                        72
   775731  08/29/2014 8:42:34 AM  08/29/2014 8:51:03 AM 39
   789858 02/26/2014 12:29:26 PM 02/26/2014 12:49:00 PM 14
   845277  04/07/2014 1:49:04 PM  04/07/2014 1:59:56 PM 41
   936749 02/14/2014 12:02:29 PM 02/14/2014 12:08:00 PM 31
   845277 05/18/2014 12:09:35 PM                        43
   954953  03/05/2014 9:47:11 AM 03/05/2014 10:14:00 AM 24
```

What I want to do is,

```
   First)  find x1(Id numbers) that have NA in their x3(DataTime) column in this example 549395 
   Second) Identify other observations with similar Id number in this example obs1 and obs4 
   Third)  Compare the date value in x2 for these matching observations (Obs1 & Obs4) 
   Fourth) If the date value in x2 matches then replace the corresponding x4 to 0
```

In this case, the x4 for obs1 and obs4 will be 0 because obs 4 contains missing X3 , id number is 549395 and the x2 for Id 549395 matches 06/16/2014....

Although x3 for obs 0 is missing the ID number 845277 has two matching observations (obs9 and obs 7) however the x2 for this id 845277 is not the same (04/07/2014 ,05/18/201) so x4 should not be changed to 0.

The final dataset should look like this.

```
   X1     X2                     X3                      X4
   549395 06/16/2014 10:45:24 AM 06/04/2014 11:10:03 AM    0
   678018 09/16/2014 10:02:46 AM 09/16/2014 10:23:00 AM 21
   706197 02/12/2014 12:00:13 PM 02/12/2014 12:21:00 PM 10
   549395 06/16/2014 10:45:24 AM                           0
   775731  08/29/2014 8:42:34 AM  08/29/2014 8:51:03 AM 39
   789858 02/26/2014 12:29:26 PM 02/26/2014 12:49:00 PM 14
   845277  04/07/2014 1:49:04 PM  04/07/2014 1:59:56 PM 41
   936749 02/14/2014 12:02:29 PM 02/14/2014 12:08:00 PM 31
   845277 05/18/2014 12:09:35 PM                        43
   954953  03/05/2014 9:47:11 AM 03/05/2014 10:14:00 AM 24
```

Need help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the dataset provided, the `NA`s are `"NA"` or the levels of `factor` column.  You could check the `str` of `test2`

```
str(test2)
#'data.frame':  10 obs. of  3 variables:
#$ X1: Factor w/ 8 levels "549395","678018",..: 1 2 3 1 4 5 6 7 6 8
#$ X2: Factor w/ 9 levels "02/12/2014 12:21:00 PM",..: 6 8 1 9 7 3 5 2 9 4
#$ X3: Factor w/ 10 levels "10","14","21",..: 10 3 1 9 6 2 7 5 8 4

 levels(test2$X2)
#[1] "02/12/2014 12:21:00 PM" "02/14/2014 12:08:00 PM" "02/26/2014 12:49:00 PM"
#[4] "03/05/2014 10:14:00 AM" "04/07/2014 1:59:56 PM"  "06/04/2014 11:10:03 AM"
#[7] "08/29/2014 8:51:03 AM"  "09/16/2014 10:23:00 AM" "NA"
```

When you read the dataset using `read.table/read.csv`, you can specify `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` and use `na.strings='NA'`.  For the current dataset, first convert the `X3` column to `numeric` and then create a logical index by checking which row of `X2` has `'NA'` level

```
test2$X3 <- as.numeric(levels(test2$X3))[test2$X3]
test2$X3[test2$X1 %in% test2$X1[test2$X2 == 'NA']] <- 0

test2$X3
#[1]  0 21 10  0 39 14  0 31  0 24
```

If the `NAs` were real `NA`, you could try (as commented by @David Arenburg)

```
test2$X3[test2$X1 %in% test2$X1[is.na(test2$X2)]] <- 0
```

#### Update

May be this helps for the updated question.  Note that in the new dataset, you have `''` instead of `NA`.

```
 indx <-  with(test2, as.logical(ave(X2, X1, FUN=function(x)
             all(duplicated(x)|duplicated(x,fromLast=TRUE))))) & 
                               test2$X1 %in% test2$X1[test2$X3=='']

  test2$X4[indx] <- 0
```

Or you can use

```
 library(dplyr)
 test2 %>% 
       group_by(X1) %>%
       mutate(X4= replace(X4,all(X3=='' &
          duplicated(X2)|duplicated(X2,fromLast=TRUE)), 0))
 #       X1        X2              X3 X4
 #1  549395 6/16/2014  6/4/2014 11:10  0
 #2  678018 9/16/2014 9/16/2014 10:23 21
 #3  706197 2/12/2014 2/12/2014 12:21 10
 #4  549395 6/16/2014                  0
 #5  775731 8/29/2014  8/29/2014 8:51 39
 #6  789858 2/26/2014 2/26/2014 12:49 14
 #7  845277  4/7/2014  4/7/2014 13:59 41
 #8  936749 2/14/2014 2/14/2014 12:08 31
 #9  845277 5/18/2014                 43
 #10 954953  3/5/2014  3/5/2014 10:14 24
```

Or using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(test2)[,X4:=replace(X4, all(X3=='' & 
      duplicated(X2)|duplicated(X2,fromLast=TRUE)),0L) , by=X1]
```

Comment: @Science11 Sorry, I missed that part. Please check the update

Comment: I apologize I did not state my problem accurately, I have modified my question with an new criteria...:(